# PHP get array objects by index

Tags: php

Say that I have a PHP array like so:

```
$marr = array(
"name" => "John",
"age" => 33
);

print_r($marr[0]);
```

This code gives me an error of `Undefined offset: 0.` What I am trying to achieve is to print the `name` part of the array without specifying it in my print request, and instead doing it via an index number. So instead of having to print `$marr['name']` is there a way for me to just assign an index, much like what I tried to do in my example?

Comment: PHP arrays are also dictionaries, so `'name'` is a valid index you can use, why insist on indices that are not even guaranteed? Make sure you study the PHP documentation to get a full view.

Comment: You cannot use `$marr[0]` here because you have set the key to `name` already. But even if you try to use with indexes this is not a good behavior. The array could change unexpected and you will end in different results. Just stick with the named keys.

Comment: array_values($marr)[0] will work. The order is guaranteed, so note that the array must be defined so that 'name' is the first key = value pair defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$marr = [
    "name" => "John",
    "age"  => 33
];

print_r(array_values($marr)[0]);
```

The order is guaranteed (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so as long as "name" is defined first, access with and index of 0 works.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have a multidimensional array. You can access by using the key to get the value. In example: `echo $marr["name"];` will print you `John`.

You tried to access a array by index. But it doesn't work on multidimensional array. Then the array have to look like this:

```php
$arr = [
  "John",
  "33"
];

print_r($arr[0]); // print you John
```

To archive this kind of array you can convert your multidimensional array with the PHP function `array_values($marr)`.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-values.php